# Property 'props' does not work in userscript (for khanacademy)

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey, userscripts, khan-academy

I don't know if this question is against the rules, so I'll understand if it gets deleted or if I receive a punishment.

The following script creates an alert with the answer of a multiple choice exercise in Khanacademy. It works basically in all exercises that have an "A B C" type selectable multiple choice answers. It used to work perfectly before, but now the console spits out the following error:

```
ERROR: Execution of script 'KA Multiple Choice' failed! Cannot read property 'props' of undefined
```

I don't know if the method used was patched, but I would like to know if I can do anything to fix it.

Here is the script:

```
const arrayanswers = JSON.parse(window["./javascript/app-shell-package/app-entry.js"].props.componentProps.initialItem.itemData).question.widgets["radio 1"].options.choices,
filtered = arrayanswers.reduce((acc, item, index) => ((item.correct) ? [...acc, index] : acc), []);

alert("0 = Option A" + '\n' + "1 = Option B" + '\n' + "2 = Option C" + '\n' + "3 = Option D" + '\n' + "Answers are: " + `${filtered.join(', ')}`);
```

**EDIT: I got it working by using a Snippet from Chrome. However, I would still like to make it work in Tampermonkey.**

Comment: The error means that `window["./javascript/app-shell-package/app-entry.js"]` is `undefined`, which is hardly surprising. What is it that you expect that to be?

Comment: The original JSON.parse was `JSON.parse(window["./javascript/app-shell-package/app-entry.js"].props.componentProps.initialItem.itemData).question.widgets["radio 1"].options.choices` which outputted the array of possible answers. The `filtered` variable obviously filters out the arrays which have the incorrect answer.

When I input that JSON.parse in the console, it does work and the arrays do show

Comment: It seems to be undefined as soon as I put the JSON.parse into a variable. Executing it directly on console works perfectly well.

Comment: You may need a `// @grant unsafeWindow` and use unsafeWindow instead of window. See TM docs for more information

Comment: I tried this `unsafeWindow`. It didn't change anything with Tampermonkey. The script still works perfectly if it is entered directly in the Console or run as a snippet in the dev panel.